# Make a checkbox look independently to 2 dropdown box'values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a calculation form, calculating the total cost of a product by dropdown selection and checkboxes. There are 2 different types of products (dropdowns) and several options to add (checkboxes). 2 of those options/checkboxes have a percentage value, meaning that if the product selected in the dropdown has a value of 10 and the checkbox with a 10% value is checked, the total value/cost becomes 11.

So far this works, however, now the checkboxes containing a percentage value are only pointing to 1 dropdown box and I would like them to look at both. So if Product 1 (dropdown 1) is selected then the percentage value needs to be added based on that price, but if Product 2 (dropdown 2) is selected that same checkbox should calculate its percentage value based on the price of Product 2.

In my code this looks as follows:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="NonTrans" name='NonTrans'
onchange="calculateTotal()">
<option value="1Non">Select Dimensions</option>
<option value="2Non">3,00 6,40 0,85 (3)</option>
<option value="3Non">3,00 7,50 0,85 (3)</option>

<select id="FullTrans" name='FullTrans' onchange="calculateTotal()">
<option value="1Full">Select Dimensions</option>
<option value="2Full">3,00 6,40 0,85 (3)</option>
<option value="3Full">3,00 7,50 0,85 (3)</option>
```

This is the HTML part for the 1st and 2nd dropdown box containing the main products.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optionprice" name='optionprice' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
```

And this is the HTML part for the checkbox containing a percentage value.

```
 var NonTrans_prices = new Array();
 NonTrans_prices["1Non"] = 0;
 NonTrans_prices["2Non"] = 5994;
 NonTrans_prices["3Non"] = 7076;

function NonTrans() {
   var NonTransPrice = 0;

   var theForm = document.forms["GRANADANEO"];

   var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["NonTrans"];

   NonTransPrice = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];

   return NonTransPrice;
 }

 var FullTrans_prices = new Array();
 FullTrans_prices["1Full"] = 0;
 FullTrans_prices["2Full"] = 5994;
 FullTrans_prices["3Full"] = 7076;

function FullTrans() {
   var FullTransPrice = 0;

   var theForm = document.forms["GRANADANEO"];

   var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["FullTrans"];

   FullTransPrice = FullTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];

   return FullTransPrice;
 }
```

This is the JavaScript part for the 1st & 2nd dropdown box.

```
 function HoutImitatie() {
   var chkOptionPrice = document.getElementById("optionprice");
   var theForm = document.forms["GRANADANEO"];
   var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["NonTrans"];
   var lstNonTransValue = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];

   var inscriptionPrice = 0;

   if (optionprice.checked === true) {

     var price = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];

     var percentage = 20;
     inscriptionPrice = (price * percentage) / 100;
   }

   return inscriptionPrice;
 }
```

And finally this is the JavaScript part for the checkbox containing the percentage value.

```
function calculateTotal() {

   var cakePrice = NonTrans() + FullTrans() + SchuifdeurVoorzijde();


   var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
   divobj.style.display = 'block';
   divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price: " + cakePrice + " \u20ac";

 }
```

I have tried several things, however I am no JavaScript programmer, so things I tried involve simply adding the variable of the FullTrans_prices inside the function of HoutImitatie, and I have tried that in several forms. Most of them don't show any result, the best I had was a NaN.

I want to add the full code to JSFiddle for you guys, however for some reason I don't see my Total score in there while I do see it on the live version here: [Calculator live](http://www.axesseurope.be/appalacarte/Calculator/axess_calculator.html)

I can provide the complete code to play with to anyone however it didn't seem wise to me to put over 2000 lines of code in this question.

My complete code is viewable through: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/je5qpb9h/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept on trying and trying and finally I got it to work with the following code:

```
function HoutImitatie() {
   var chkOptionPrice = document.getElementById("optionprice");
   var theForm = document.forms["GRANADANEO"];
   var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["NonTrans"];
//I added the line below exactly in the same form as the line above:
   var selectedFilling2 = theForm.elements["FullTrans"]
   var lstNonTransValue = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value];

   var inscriptionPrice = 0;

   if (optionprice.checked === true) {
//And I added that variable again below in the definition of price:
     var price = NonTrans_prices[selectedFilling.value] + FullTrans_prices[selectedFilling2.value];

     var percentage = 20;
     inscriptionPrice = (price * percentage) / 100;
   }

   return inscriptionPrice;
 }
```

I have no idea whether this is best practice though since this really was a lucky shot. Should anyone have better suggestions or remarks regarding my code please do state I wouldn't want to bring anyone else on a wrong path because of the solution I found that suited my case.

Comment: If it works in all conceivable circumstances and doesn't drain system resources too much, I'd say: fine, there may well be a better way, but carry on with bigger issues - you can come back to this later if necessary